Clearing the browser history and django session
I have an application in django, in it you can add a tourist tour to your cart, the basket is stored in the session. The tour has a model, and the models field is available.It is responsible for the available seats of the tour. When adding a tourist tour to the cart, the available field is reduced by 1 and so on. When I add a tour to the cart, it will be in session, then I will clear the browser history, the session will be deleted, but the number of available seats will not change.How do I catch the history deletion event so that I can call the update_available() function to return free spaces?
I'm thinking of trying to catch the history cleanup event, call fetch, and call the update_available() function in python. but I didn't find anything about such an event on the Internet.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

you have to change available seats in model on your own - deleting session can't change this value.

without minimal working code it is hard to say what you are doing in code.
